# How to use imshow with datetime axis with variable timesteps and gaps in the data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-datetime, imshow

This questions explains how to use `datetime` objects on x axis:
[Dates in the xaxis for a matplotlib plot with imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139595/dates-in-the-xaxis-for-a-matplotlib-plot-with-imshow)
and that works perfectly.

But what I have is measurement data which correspond to different time intervals of 1 minute or 3 minutes and there are also gaps in the data of varying durations - 10 minutes or 1 hour or anything in between. 
Data is in a dictionary with datetime keys and numpy array values. Some of the keys are 1 min and some are 3 min apart. There are also gaps in the the data which are > 3min, usually not < 10 min.

If I plot this with:
`ax.imshow(arr, extent = [x1, x2,  y1, y2], aspect='auto')`
where x1 and x2 are start and end times and y1 and y2 vertical dimension, and arr is 2d numpy array generated form the dictionary values mentioned above,
the data will be evenly spread across the time axis, and I want gaps to be visible, and I want data to be plotted with regard to its time resolution and time of measurement.

I thought of writing `nans` to my array to fill the gaps, but then I would also have to copy data of 3 min time step to fill the 'gaps' because most of the data is available each minute.

I am looking for a better and more elegant option. Of course I do not have to use `imshow()` if there is another way.

Comment: Please provide what you have so far

Comment: I rephrased the question hoping it will be easier to understand. The extent option is not flexible enough for my needs, so am asking for an idea or a solution. Not sure what else should I provide.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution for the described problem using matplotlib. But plotly provides a solution, since the [Heatmap](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Heatmap.html) object allows also to take time as a parameter:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# Assuming image is your image and times is your array of time values
image = np.random.rand(10, 10)  # Replace with your image
times = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 46])  # Replace with your times

# Create a 2D heatmap to represent the image
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
    z=image,
    x=times,
    colorscale='Gray',
    showscale=False
))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title="Time",
    yaxis_title="Y",
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=500,
    margin=dict(
        l=50,
        r=50,
        b=100,
        t=100,
        pad=4
    )
)

fig.show()
```