# How to align twin-axis of datetimes over invisible original axis of floats/ints in imshow?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib, imshow

I would like to show datetimes as ticklabels on the x-axis of a plot via `ax.imshow()`. I first tried putting the limits (as `datetime` objects) into extent, but it appears that extent only accepts arguments of `type <float/int>`. So instead, I would like to create the original plot via `ax.imshow(...)`, then make the x-axis invisible, then add in the correct `xticks` and `xlim`.

I found a similar problem solved using a different approach [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139595/dates-in-the-xaxis-for-a-matplotlib-plot-with-imshow), but I think my use-case is slightly different; I don't need to convert any time-stamps, but I do know the `xlim` of the data (in terms of `datetime` objects). Also, I do not think the suggested use of `matplotlib.dates.date2num` fits my use-case since some of the data is spaced less than one day apart, but `date2num` uses [days as a base-unit](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num).

I am stuck trying to make this work using my alternate approach; a simple mini-example is below.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

def f(x, y):
    return np.sqrt(np.square(x) + np.square(y))

## SAMPLE DATA
x = np.arange(10) ## elapsed minutes
y = np.square(x) ## arbitrary y-values
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

## DATETIMES FOR ALTERNATE AXIS
lower_dt = datetime.datetime(1999, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
# upper_dt = datetime.datetime(2001, 10, 31, 0, 0, 0)
upper_dt = datetime.datetime(1999, 1, 1, x.size-1, 0, 0)

## DO PLOT
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
# ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ax.imshow(
    Z,
    origin='lower',
    cmap='Oranges',
    norm=Normalize(vmin=np.nanmin(Z), vmax=np.nanmax(X)),
    extent=(x[0], x[-1], y[0], y[-1]))

## CONVERT XTICKLABELS OF X-AXIS TO DATETIME
mirror_ax = ax.twiny()
# mirror_ax = ax.figure.add_subplot(ax.get_subplotspec(), frameon=False)
mirror_ax.set_xlim([lower_dt, upper_dt])

plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

The obtained plot can be seen here:
[image]

I notice that the `xticks` are shown at the top instead of the bottom of the plot - this is unwanted behavior; using `ax.tick_top` (commented out above) does not change this. Even worse, the x-axis limits are not retained. I realize I could manually change the xticklabels via `ax.get_xticks()` and `ax.set_xticklabels(...)`, but I would prefer to leave that for date-formatters and date-locators via matplotlib.

How can I use the approach outlined above to create a "mirror/alternate" x-axis of datetime units such that this x-axis is the same size/orientation of the "original/invisible" x-axis of float/integer units?

Comment: I’d suggest you use pcolormesh instead of imshow.

Comment: It seems you do not want to create a twin axis but use `ax.xaxis.tick_top()` instead to move the x-labels to the desired position. Why did you comment it out and use your approach instead?